# Running a socket server in php from a server

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

Well lately I have searched much information about php socket servers, I have seen run on a PC, but can not find a way to run it on the server.
My aim is to make a chat with a server using php websokets.
I'll be thankful to whoever can give me some suggestions, or the steps to try this tool.

Comment: necessarily from the server? Why not from command line SAPI? php YOURFILE > /dev/null &

Answer (score 2):

Just use [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) its more simplified that PHP socket here is a [simple chat server](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world)

```
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new Chat()
      , 8080
    );

    $server->run();
```

You can also consider [phpwebsocket](https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Just did a chat using php sockets and tool html5, WebSocket.
Everything works perfectly on 'localhost', the thing is to start listening to the customer, must run the server.php on the server.
And not like XD.

Comment: Oh i get you now .. what exactly is the error you are getting ? Have you configured your firewall to accept connection from that PORT ?

Comment: Maybe he is using shared hosting where there's not root access to the server?

Comment: I do not see any error. I want to know how I can run a php socket server implemented from the server.
For example to do it from the pc using php.exe-q server.php
By doing that I can run the script to listen to customers.
As I do this in a hosting? I use 2freehosting.com, SSH access.
Thank you very much for the reply!

Comment: Yes you can do that `php bin/chat-server.php` would start the chat server i just added